# Visitor pattern in tree-structures

Tags: java, api, design-patterns

I want to revise my usage of the visitor pattern for tree-structures and different node types. Every node in the tree-structure has to implement a callback method and the visitor implementation must implement something like the following for each node type (or at least the types he's interested in):

```
/**
 * Do something when visiting a {@link CommentNode}.
 * 
 * @param pNode
 *          the {@link CommentNode}
 */
EVisitResult visit(final @Nonnull CommentNode pNode);

/**
 * Do something when visiting an {@link ElementNode}.
 * 
 * @param pNode
 *          the {@link ElementNode}
 */
EVisitResult visit(final @Nonnull ElementNode pNode);
```

I'm using transactional cursor semantics to navigate through the tree-structure and provide an acceptVisitor-method, that is in the cursor I've implemented the following:

```
@Override
public EVisitResult acceptVisitor(final @Nonnull IVisitor pVisitor) {
  assertNotClosed();
  return mCurrentNode.acceptVisitor(pVisitor);
}
```

However the visitor is a flaw in the API, because exposing the nodes itself, for instance `ElementNode` is very dangerous, because modifications which are allowed for every node-type should only be able from within a specific write-transaction (implemented as a cursor which provides methods to traverse a tree-structure). Otherwise the changes are not visible and not made persistent during a `commit()`.

Any suggestions on how to circumvent this situation? I somehow doubt I'm able to provide the visitor-interface as method signatures for sure have to be different...

Ok, I will provide Immutable "wrapper" or proxy classes:

```
/** Mutable {@link CommentNode}. */
private final CommentNode mNode;

/**
 * Constructor.
 * 
 * @param pNode
 *          mutable {@link CommentNode}
 */
private ImmutableComment(final @Nonnull CommentNode pNode) {
  mNode = checkNotNull(pNode);
}

/**
 * Get an immutable comment
 * 
 * @param pNode
 *          the {@link CommentNode} which should be immutable
 * @return an immutable instance
 */
public static ImmutableComment of(final @Nonnull CommentNode pNode) {
  return new ImmutableComment(pNode);
}
```

Comment: you could let the cursor class wrap your nodes with a proxy, that would expose the same interface as the nodes to the visitor. Then no visitor can modify a node directly. The transaction logic can be put in the proxies or the proxies delegate back to the cursor for that.

Comment: For instance providing an immutable "wrapper" or proxy for each node type which expects the modifyable instance in its constructor? Nice idea :-)

Comment: @nansen, care to turn that comment into an answer?

Comment: @MvG: thought of it more as a hint than an answer. But, ok, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let the cursor class wrap your nodes with a proxy, that would expose the same interface as the nodes to the visitor. Then no visitor can modify a node directly. The transaction logic can be put in the proxies or the proxies delegate back to the cursor for that.